# Case Status Changing from Email Message Workflow not working

Tags: workflow, case, emailmessage, email2case

I've tried creating a simple workflow to change the case status from "Resolved" to "Reopened" when a customer replied to the case. I've found a few guides online to do this but for some reason it doesn't appear to function.

Here is the workflow rules: [image]

And here is the workflow action: [image]

Debug log:

> 10:29:37.217 (217367041)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Workflow:EmailMessage
>   10:29:37.217 (231870417)|WF_RULE_EVAL_BEGIN|Workflow
>   10:29:37.217 (231915699)|WF_CRITERIA_BEGIN|[Email Message:  02s1D000000PBXs]|Email Message Test|01Q1D0000007b3K|ON_CREATE_ONLY|0
>   10:29:37.217 (235993912)|WF_RULE_FILTER|[Email Message : Is Incoming equals true] 
>   AND [Case : Status equals Resolved]
>   10:29:37.217 (236022204)|WF_RULE_EVAL_VALUE|false
>   10:29:37.217 (236029789)|WF_CRITERIA_END|false
>   10:29:37.217 (236047673)|WF_CRITERIA_BEGIN|[Email Message:  02s1D000000PBXs]|Email_Message_test3011D000000BSAn|01Q1D0000007azX|ON_CREATE_ONLY|0
>   10:29:37.217 (236230003)|WF_FORMULA|Formula:ENCODED:[treatNullAsNull]true|Values:
>   10:29:37.217 (236241493)|WF_CRITERIA_END|true
>   10:29:37.217 (236801664)|WF_SPOOL_ACTION_BEGIN|Workflow
>   10:29:37.217 (236838041)|WF_ACTION| Flow Trigger: 1;
>   10:29:37.217 (236844210)|WF_RULE_EVAL_END
>   10:29:37.217 (261839312)|WF_FLOW_ACTION_BEGIN|09L1D0000000sKi
>   10:29:37.217 (261899102)|WF_FLOW_ACTION_DETAIL|09L1D0000000sKi|[Email Message:  02s1D000000PBXs]|Id=09L1D0000000sKi|CurrentRule:Email_Message_test3011D000000BSAn (Id=01Q1D0000007azX)
>   10:29:37.217 (262376078)|WF_FLOW_ACTION_DETAIL|Param Name: myVariable_current, Param Value: ENCODED:{![treatNullAsNull]{!ID:this}}, Evaluated Param Value: {Entity type: EmailMessage, id: 02s1D000000PBXsQAO}|Param Name: myVariable_old, Param Value: {!old}, Evaluated Param Value: null
>   10:29:37.217 (267526558)|WF_FLOW_ACTION_END|09L1D0000000sKi
>   10:29:37.217 (267646688)|WF_ACTIONS_END| Flow Trigger: 1;

Would anyone perhaps know why this isn't functioning or know of an alternative method?

Comment: What did you do to test? It looks like it evaluated to false in the WF criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the issue. I didn't test by sending and replying to the Proxy email designated in the email-to-case setting. It also requires the setting of including the thread ID in the subject or body also located in the Email-to-case setting.